# Display correct username with parent comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now the username that displays under all comments are from the person who is currently logged in. It does not display the correct user who actually made the comment. I was having trouble with this earlier however, I thought I resolved it. I am a Rails newbie so go easy please. Please let me know if more code snippets are needed. Thank you in advance.

**view / _comment**

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
    <p>
        <strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</strong></br>
        <%= h(comment.body) %>
        <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', [@post, comment], :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**view / _form**

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Comment Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = Comment.new
  end


  def create
    @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body))
    @comment.username = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def show
  @commment = Comment.find params[:id]
end
```

**Model / Comments**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
drop_table :comments
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, :post_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of adding a username in your comments you should use a proper association between comments and users which will then give you access to user object instead of just a username field

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. However, when I tried it didn't work. What would you recommend being the best way to set it up? I'm still gaining my barriers. I have it set up for posts and users. Thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I see your comment objects have a `username` property (from the `create` method)?:

```
@comment.username = current_user
```

If so, change `current_user.name` to `comment.username`:

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
    <p>
        <strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</strong></br>
        <%= h(comment.body) %>
        <strong><%= comment.username %></strong>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', [@post, comment], :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

---

**EDIT 28/08/2014**

#### For better association:

If you'd like it so that you must be a user in your system to leave a comment, you could implement your relationships like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # they can create posts
  has_many :posts

  # they can add comments to posts
  has_many :comments

  # they have comments directed back at them through the posts they create
  has_many :responses, :through => :posts, :source => :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # each post is created by a user
  belongs_to :user

  # a post has comments
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # each comment is attached to a post
  belongs_to :post

  # each comment is created by a user
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This association would allow you association proxy like:

- `@user.comments` - returns the comments the user has made, regardless of post
- `@user.responses` - returns the comments attached to posts made by the user
- `@comment.user` - returns the user object of the user who posted the comment
- `@comment.post` - returns the post that the comment belongs to
- `@post.comments` - returns all comments attached to a post
- And so on...

Using this, you could associate the comment to a user using `@comment.user_id = current_user.id` in your `CommentsController`.  Then in your view, instead of `<%= current_user.name %>`, you would put `<%= comment.user.name %>` (substitute `name` for whatever your attribute is called).

***Remember***: this way assumes that you must be a user in your system to be able to leave a comment.  If it doesn't matter whether the commenter is a user in your system or not...

---

#### For no direct association between comments and users:

The Comment model would need to hold the name of person who made it. In your migration, the Comment model only has the `:body` and `:post_id` tables created (`timestamps` are automatic by convention):

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.integer :post_id
  t.text :body

  t.timestamps
end
```

You've already told the `CommentsController` to accept two parameters in the `create` method:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body))
```

So, you don't need to create another property ("username"); you can just add the `commenter` property to your Comment model! First run `rake db:migrate` to make sure you don't have any outstanding migrations, then generate a migration to add a "commenters" column to your "comments" table:

```
rails generate migration add_commenter_to_comments commenter:string
```

After that, run `rake db:migrate` as usual to run the new migration.  Once it's done, you'll be able to use `@comment.commenter` in your controller and view thanks to some ActiveRecord magic. Make sure you add a spot in your comment form for a person to add their name!

P.S. Are you, by chance, reading *[Beginning Rails (4)](http://www.apress.com/9781430260349)*?  This code looks awfully familiar...

P.P.S.  I'm a Rails n00b, too.  I'm learning right along with you... :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I change it to comment.username I get an undefined method `username' for #<Comment:0x007fa1dc429c50>.

Comment: See Bryan Wongs points: if you don't have the column "username" defined in your "comments" table in your database, the username is not being stored. That's why ActiveRecord can't map it to a method for the object, or your Comment model doesn't have the method "username" defined in `app/models/comment.rb`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I accidentally edited your post by adding in the model and migration, apologies. It was supposed to go into the main question. I tried comment.username however, I am getting an undefined method `username' for #<Comment:0x007faa9ca47240>. Where in the migration do I need to add username? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are assigning the user object (in this case current_user), into @comment.username = current_user

```
@comment.username = current_user
```

You should not pass the whole user object into it in that manner, it should be the appropriate field from the user object; e.g.

```
@comment.username = current_user.username
```

Here are a few pointers to clarify:

- Did you define the username method or column in your Comment model?
- What is the field from your User object which you want to save into the username field?
- Have you considered using association for your User, Post and Comment model (at least you do not need to manually do the input in such manner when you can build it via associations)

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added my current comment model and migration. I am extremely new to rails so forgive me. What would be the best way to set up associations? I tried before however, I was having difficulty with getting the username to display as well. Thank you again for your help and advice.

Comment: @Annette, are you trying associate username as part of the data field in User model? Firstly, do you have a username field in your user table? If not, you can generate via `rails g migration add_username_to_user username:string` and check the generated migration file. @thankyour has a good example of setting up associations